# Magento Notfication Bar Not Displaying in Magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: notification

I usually set up a notification to inform our customers of any holiday or shutdown breaks we have. This year however I've been unable to. Unsure if it's an extension conflict or in light of some recent security patches. Has anyone else experienced and remedied this?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try this?  https://magecomp.com/magento-notification-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance your theme was modified since last year? There should be something in your theme files (default Magento would be like app/design/default/page/1column.phtml)

Judging by your screenshot, you're using https://github.com/justinstern/magento-notification-bar

From their readme;

The Notification Bar hooks into the after_body_start block which should appear in the page.xml layout file and be echoed in the page template files (ie 1column.phtml):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
```

Resulting in something like the following appearing in your page source if everything is working properly:

```
<div id="notification-bar"><div id="notification"><span class="notification-content">My Message</span></div></div>
```